# Readers-Writer Problem Extended Version, Readers traverse the whole file

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, operating-system, synchronization

## Background

I am currently in an operating system course and the lecture introduced to us the multiple reader - writer problem:

Writer:

```cpp
do {
            wait (wrt) ;
            // writing is performed
            signal (wrt) ;
} while (true)
```

Reader:

```cpp
do  {
    wait (mutex);
    readcount ++;
    if (readcount == 1)  wait (wrt);
    signal (mutex)
    // reading is performed
    wait (mutex);
    readcount--;
    if (readcount  == 0)  signal (wrt) ;
    signal (mutex) ;
} while (true)
```

- If a writer is in the CS, and n readers are waiting, then one reader is queued on `wrt`, and n-1 readers are queued on `mutex`.
- When a writer executes `signal(wrt)`, execution will be resumed, selection of which one to execute is made by the scheduler.

## Description:

I know there are a lot of resources out there about reader and writer problems. But I just thought of an interesting scenario, what if, the readers are actually used to traverse the text written by the writer?

#### A more challenging extended version:

1 writer constantly writing stuffs to a text file

n readers read the whole file but every time only the most currently written text by the writer.

For the **n readers**, each **reader** every time **only read one part** of the text file, for example:
for a text file containing:

```
[Part A][Part B]...[Part N]
```

The **first reader** only read `[part A]`, then the **next reader** read `[part B]` and so on, until the whole text file is read by all the children, then parent will **clear the existing stuffs** in the text file and write something on it again, after it finishes writing, the reader-threads can continue reading, and over and over again

#### Question:

Is it possible to be achieved by using only the mutex `wrt`, `mutex` as above? If not, how can I achieve it?

**my idea so far:**

> we may need to define a buffer size and a char pointer to keep track on how much of the text file have been read by all threads. Suppose that we can use condition variables, but still, synchronization is a problem.

I apologize if you find my description confusing. I will try to express it as clear as possible. I also welcome any idea, any suggestions, a (pseudo) code implementation is better but not a must.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking that reader can read distinct data from DB but see, in reader writers problem in IPC , multiple readers can read and enter into CS, readers can be different so ultimately if here 2 reader want to read part A , they will read. what is the point of deciding that what will reader's going to read. Correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: What I actually want to do is using multiple reader-threads to traverse the whole files. "Distinct" is probably a bad choice of word on this, sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: so you have to change the code itself, I don't think we can achieve this by using semaphores. We have to use possible locking protocols on DB file/respective records.

Comment: Hmm, what if we can use condition variables? Will that change anything?

Answer (score 0):

## Here is my proposed pseudo code solution:

```
full = 0, empty = 0, mutex = 1, read_mutex = 1
-------------------------------
```

WRITER:

```
while read_count < file_count:
    //writer stuff -> buffer, num_read
    post(full)
    wait(empty)
```

READER_THREADS

````
while(read_count < file_count):
    wait(mutex)
    readerCount++;
    if(readerCount == 1): wait(full)
    wait(read_mutex)
    while already_read < num_read:
        //read the small buffer
        //update already_read
        post(read_mutex)
        post(mutex)
    readerCount--
    if(readerCount  == 0) : post(empty)
    post(mutex)```
````